# I have Jquery set to read a JSON file but only i see it on the website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a few friends helping me out by going on to the website to see if it comes up, but they show me that nothing comes up, and for me all the stuff from the json file shows up for me

**PHP file for AJAX:**

```
<?php 
  include '../filter.php';
  $chatjson = file_get_contents('chats.json');
  $chatarray = array();
  $sender = SecurePost($_POST["sender"]);
  $message = SecurePost($_POST["message"]);

  if ($sender || $message) {
      $chatarray[] = array('sender' => $sender, 'message' => $message);
      if (json_decode($chatjson)) {
          $chatarray[] = json_decode($chatjson);
      }

      file_put_contents("chats.json",json_encode($chatarray));
  }
?>
```

**AJAX**

```
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
   var chats = [];
   var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }   
    j(document).ready(function()
    {
        setInterval(function(i){
            $.getJSON( "/Chatting/chats.json", function( data ) {
                var txt = "";
                var x;
                for (x in data) {
                    txt += data[x] + " <br />";
                }
                document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
            });
        }, 1000)
    });
```

What comes up for me:
[Picture for what comes up](http://prntscr.com/7go7ky)

For my friends, it is the same thing but nothing comes up.

Comment: Are they seeing any errors in their web developer consoles?

Comment: They get this error, my friend copy and pasted to me. TypeError: Cannot read property 'getJSON' of undefined
9chattest.php:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getJSON' of undefined

Comment: What is `$.getJSON`? You told jQuery to use `j` instead.